# How to make a non list Loop that will select 4 random numbers from 1-10, and display them, but they cannot be the same?

Tags: python, loops, random, numbers

```
import random
counter = 0
count = 0
counting = 0
valueOne = 0
valueTwo = 0
while counter ==0:
    playerOne = random.randint(1,10)
    number = random.randint(1,10)
```

About right here is where I get confused. It will run the loop, but every time it runs, the random values get reset, and even if the first time it prints a random number, the second time it might print the same and so forth.

```
    if number == playerOne:
        count = count + 1
    if number != playerOne:
        valueOne = playerOne

        if number != valueOne:

            print("lotto number",number)
            counting = counting + 1
        if counting >= 4:
            print("it took you this many trys",count)
            input('play again?')
            counting = 0
            count = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should list the numbers in 1-10 (inclusive) then randomly sample them.

```
random.sample(range(1,11), 4)
```

[random.sample docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

[range docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: Thankyou for the example. I will look more into those docs and give an update after i experiment a little.